# Multiple Objects, Multiple UV's and Multiple Shape Keys Conundrum

Tags: uv, selection-tools, shape-keys

I have a ton of objects, with multiple shape keys, what I need is a way to get uv's for each shape key on all objects at once. Any ideas how to do this?

Even if I just had multiple objects with multiple, matching uv's I cannot choose all objects and choose specific uv channels to edit for all objects (I can only select the specific UV for the 'active' object, not all selected... The same applies with trying to select a specific shape key on multiple objects).

It's a real predicament and I would be eternally greatful for a solution).

Comment: how about a script?

Answer (score 0):

Select all your objects (make sure all objects have the correct shape key selected and the correct uv set go active) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter Edit Mode for all objects at once. Then you can edit all the UVs all at once.

You should also think about the reason you got into a big mess where you would need to do that and if there is another way. If not, here is a simple script template to select all the shapekeys and all the uvs at once. if the UV is not present yet it will be created.

```
import bpy
UV_name = "Your UV Name"
for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    o.active_shape_key_index = 0
    if UV_name not in o.data.uv_layers:
        o.data.uv_layers.new(name=UV_name)
    o.data.uv_layers[UV_name].active = true
```

Comment: Well that's the problem when you have 450-ish objects; selecting all 450 shape keys and UV channels :-(

Comment: you can script the selecting, or you can copy the UVs, but I think for that also scripting would be useful. Maybe you can explain a little bit more (in your question), whats the connection between you objects (same shape, same shape keys, same UVs, whatever) and it would be useful to know roughly how many vertices they have.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. 

So I have an object (a bridge) that is fractured into 400 pieces (with the origins centered on each piece). Each piece is then given a shape key in the form of an organic rock. At this point the UV's for the bridge material will not work, a new set of uv's is required for the rock form. For this I would simply select all 400 pieces, add a new UV and run a 'Project UV' on the new channel.

Comment: There are a couple issues here; a) I cannot add a new UV to all 400 objects at once, b) even if I had a second UV on all 400 objects, I cannot set to the second UV on all 400 objects at once in order to edit all the uv's at once, this is further compounded by c) I cannot set the shspe key to the second shape of all 400 objects at once, nor can I d) apply a unique UV project to shape keys of an object (shape keys are not uniquely UV-able).

Comment: It's a LOT and it's confusing, but I need it for unique animation on the fractured bridge that transforms it's shape and material from organic rock to final, intact bridge (all for Unreal).

Comment: a script is still the best solution